# Modificar datos de recorrida del for each

Tags: genexus

Quería recolectar opiniones sobre la siguiente recorrida y modificación del dato por el cual estoy recorriendo.

**Pongamos un caso simple:**

```
Trn
Atributo1 *
Atributo2
Atributo3
```

**En un proc:**

```
For each order Atributo3
Where Atributo3 = 'xxxxxx'
     Atributo3 = procedure_ObtenerNuevoAtributo3( Atributo3 )
EndFor
```

Estaría modificando el valor por el cual estoy recorriendo (order) y también filtrando (where).

Creen que puede traer problemas y es mejor evitar estas cosas?
Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso, como el "where" filtra por igualdad, y no por ">=" o "<=", el order por el mismo atributo del where no va a tener un efecto visible
para ese foreach, se va a generar un select en SQL, que va a tener tanto el "order by" como el "where", pero a los efectos de la evaluación de la sentencia, el order no afecta.

Ahora, la actualización dentro del "for each" se hace luego de evaluar el select, o sea, primero se determinan los registros que cumplen la condición del where, y luego se ejecuta la asignación.

En este caso particular, el atributo que asigna es el mismo por el que filtra, pero eso no afecta la cantidad de posibles registros a actualizar, se van a actualizar todos los que cumplían la condición inicial del where.

Lo que sí afecta, es cómo se hace la asignación del nuevo valor, no particularmente por cuáles van a ser los registros a actualizar, sino por cómo GX puede optimizar la actualización.

De la forma que estás actualizando en la pregunta, al llamar a un proc dentro del foreach, lo que hace GX es generar un select para obtener todos los registros a actualizar, y luego ejecutar N veces el mismo update, uno por cada registro, llamando al procedure para obtener el nuevo valor, y asignando eso en cada update.

Si en cambio el valor retornado por el procedure fuese constante, y se pudiera asignar a una variable fuera del foreach, y luego en el foreach al attribute asignarle la variable, ej:

```
&NuevoAtributo3 = procedure_ObtenerNuevoAtributo3( 'xxxxxx' )
For each order Atributo3
Where Atributo3 = 'xxxxxx'
     Atributo3 = &NuevoAtributo3
EndFor
```

En ese caso GX en lugar de ejecutar 1 select y luego N updates, ejecuta un único update.

En la navegación del proc podes ver si GX se da cuenta que estás haciendo el mismo update a todos y lo optimiza en un solo update o no.

Comment: Gracias por resonder. Entiendo lo que decís, capaz que el ejemplo no fué feliz al poner "Where atributo3='xxxxx' "   La idea era que Atributo3 tenga diferentes valores si para actualizar. Sino generaría un Update tabla set atributo3=&NuevoAtributo3 where atributo3='xxxxx'.   Justamente lo que me surge duda es que pasa si se modifican los valores que estoy recorriendo. Con un where atributo3>'xxxxx' sería mas claro el ejemplo para el problema planteado.